# How to change the date from angular material datepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a date-picker from angular material. On click of some event, I'm getting the new date from api service. How do I change the date on some click event?

By Default, I have some date. After click the submit button, there is some api handled(assume), on subscribing the response values there is a variable with date format.

How do I change the date on some click event?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field> <br/>
<button (click)="dosomeaction()">Submit</button>


export class DatepickerOverviewExample {

   dosomeaction = function(){
     let date = "2018/09/04"; 
     //assign the above date to the input field
   } 
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfknub?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
  [(ngModel)]="dateToPass"placeholder="Choose a date">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field> <br/>
  <button (click)="dosomeaction()">Submit</button>
```

component.ts

```
  export class DatepickerOverviewExample {

  dateToPass;

 dosomeaction(){
   let date = new Date("2018/09/04");
   //assign the above date to the input field
   this.dateToPass = date;

  }
}
```

Comment: Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7. (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grjjb4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), just set the date in `ngModel`

```
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
   start_time: Date;
   dosomeaction = function(){
      start_time: new Date();
   } 
}

 <input mdInput
     name="start_time"
     #start_time="ngModel"
     date="true"
     [(ngModel)]="start_time"
     placeholder="Choose a date">
```